# "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" mas parâmetros foram definidos corretamente

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

Estou com dúvidas do porque que está retornando este erro. Segue o código:

```
public function createNewAluno($dbo, $nome, $idade, $email, $semestre, $end, $cursoid) {
            $cmd = "INSERT INTO aluno_detalhes(
                nome,
                idade,
                semestre,
                email,
                endereço,
                curso_id
            )
            VALUES(
                :nome,
                :idade,
                :semestre,
                :email,
                :endereço,
                :curso_id
            )";

            $stm = $dbo -> conn -> prepare($cmd);

            try {
                $stm -> execute([
                    ":nome" => $nome,
                    ":idade" => $idade,
                    ":semestre" => $semestre,
                    ":email" => $email,
                    ":endereço" => $end,
                    ":curso_id" => $cursoid,
                ]);
                return 1;
            } catch(Exception $ee) {
                // return 0;
                return $ee -> getMessage();
            }
        }
```

Estou chamando ele assim:

```
$rv = $pdo -> createNewAluno($dbo, "Iago Jonas", 19, "teste6@teste.com", 1, "Rua Exemplo", 10);
    echo($rv);
```

O retorno é como está no título e
[a DB em questão é essa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNk27.png). Tem outra, mas são apenas o nome dos cursos e seus respectivos id's.

Comment: Já tentou remover o `:` no array do execute? Tente deixar apenas os nomes dos campos, sem o `:`

Comment: acabei de tentar aqui e continuou a mesma coisa

Comment: @Woss fazia tempo que eu nao olhava pro PDO, o `:` no array eh opcional, portanto aceito. O motivo do problema talvez seja o cedilha (ou nome da coluna errado ou talvez conflito com a codificação).

Comment: @NerdFlanders foi isso mesmo. Troquei endereço para endereco tanto nos values quanto no array e foi. Obrigado, foi falta de costume meu.